# Haskell -- Attempting to break a String into a list of Strings on a specific set of characters

Tags: list, haskell

I am struggling to break a String into a list of Strings (which is part of a larger question) and I believe I am struggling because of I cannot fully grasp how to work with nested lists in Haskell.

Just to note, my general approach to this question may be wrong and I could look at altering the Prelude `words` function but I would like to understand what I am doing wrong first, prior to optimizing it, so I can fix my understanding. The string is `".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ."`

I am attempting to separate the string when three consecutive spaces are found in the list. I have tried to setup basic recursion to achieve this but I am struggling to build the nested sublist. I have been going around in circles so any tips would be greatly appreciated!

My current code is

```
decodeMorse :: String -> [String]
decodeMorse [] = []
decodeMorse (' ':' ':' ':xs) = [] : decodeMorse xs
decodeMorse (x:xs) = [x] : decodeMorse xs
```

This will return a list of Strings but in the format:
`[".",".",".","."," ","."," ","-",".","-","-","",".","-","-","-"," ",".",".","-"," ","-",".","."," ","."]`

When I would rather the Strings be constructed on those three spaces.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prepend the first item of the recursive call, so:

```
decodeMorse :: String -> [String]
decodeMorse "" = []
decodeMorse ss = go ss
    where go [] = [[]]
          go (' ':' ':' ':xs) = [] : decodeMorse xs
          go (x:xs) = let ~(y:ys) = go xs in (x:y) : ys
```

here `y` is thus the first sublist and we thus prepend that with `x`.

This then produces:

```
Prelude> decodeMorse ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ."
[".... . -.--",".--- ..- -.. ."]
```

It might however be better to work with a parser library where you can specify the Morse grammar, this is typically more efficient since it can convert the string in a sequence of tokens by going through the list once.

Comment: ooh what's that `~(y:ys)` syntax?

Comment: @AdamSmith: it is an *irrefutable pattern*: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html this is necessary if we will aim to split infinite lists, since then we never really get the result of `(y:ys)`. It means that we are sure that it will match that pattern. It is also useful to silence GHC's warnings about incomplete patterns.

Comment: Fascinating this, makes a lot of sense so thanks for the response. Sorry, didn't get back to you sooner but this has definitely helped! The only reason why I didn't use a module is because this work is in preparation for an exam where we can't use modules; just trying to further my understanding